# How to spyOn inner method and return a desired value?

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner, angular5

I have been trying to change the value that returns a method from a provider inside the method I am testing.

I need to force `bdbPlatforms.isBrowser()` to return `false`

I know is possible to call `spyOn()` the method and change whatever it returns like:

`spyOn(bdbPlatforms, 'isBrowser').and.returnValue(false);`

but apparently is not firing, because when I try:`expect(bdbPlatforms.isBrowser()).toHaveBeenCalled();` it fails.

The test case looks like this:

```
describe('navigation provider: test', () => {
let navigation: NavigationProvider;
let navCtrlSpy;
let bdbPlatformsSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
    navCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('NavController', ['setRoot']);
    bdbPlatformsSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('BdbPlatformsProvider', ['isBrowser']);
});

afterEach(() => {
    navCtrlSpy =  null;
    bdbPlatformsSpy = null;
});

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            NavigationProvider,
            {
                provide: BdbPlatformsProvider,
                useClass: MockBdbPlatformsProvider
            },
            {
                provide: ModalController,
                useClass: ModalControllerMock
            },
            Platform
        ],
    }).compileComponents();
    navigation = TestBed.get(NavigationProvider);
});

it('should open Master page', () => {
    navigation.platformSelect(navCtrlSpy);
    expect(navCtrlSpy.setRoot).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MasterPage');
});

it('should open Tabs page', () => {
    navigation.platformSelect(navCtrlSpy);
    bdbPlatformsSpy.isBrowser.and.callFake(() => {
        return false;
    });
    expect(navCtrlSpy.setRoot).toHaveBeenCalledWith('TabsPage');
});

});
```

and this is the method in the tested class:

```
platformSelect() {
 if(this.bdbPlatforms.isBrowser()){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot('MasterPage');
 } else {
   this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
 }
}
```

The test fails with the message

> Expected spy setRoot to have been called with [ 'TabsPage' ] but actual calls were [ 'MasterPage' ].

which means that the value is not being changed on runtime. Is it possible to spy twice in the same method? if not using something like `callFake` might work?

Comment: You need to correct BdbPlatformsProvider entry in Test Bed. Please check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct `BdbPlatformsProvider` entry in Test Bed.
Try doing following:

### 1. Create Spy of bdbPlatforms.

```
    let bdbPlatformsSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('BdbPlatformsProvider', ['isBrowser']);
    bdbPlatformsSpy.isBrowser.and.callFake(function () {
        return false;
    });
```

### 2. Add it's entry in test bed as below:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      declarations: [
        ..............
      ],

      providers: [
        ..............

        {
          provide: BdbPlatformsProvider,
          useValue: bdbPlatformsSpy
        }
        ..............
      ],

      imports: [
        ............
      ]

    }).compileComponents();

  }));
```

Then it should work.

Comment: ok, I will try this, I think I was missing jasmine spy objects, thanks ill come back with the feedback

Comment: No, I could not make it work, please check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
spyOn(bdbPlatforms, 'isBrowser').and.callFake(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Explanation: the first parameter is the object if any, the second is the method to spyOn, then the callback simply returns whatever value you want to return ( a mocked value, or predefined value )

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code for reference. Code-only answers have low utility and are often confusing.

Comment: I agree with Robert, it was not really clear for me how to implement the spyOn methods